# Python - Picking a Random Column or Row from 3x3 NP Array

Tags: python-3.x, random, numpy

I set up a 3x3 grid using numPy.

```
grid = np.array([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6],
                [7,8,9]])
```

I can have the user input something in specific places ([1,1]) would be in the "5" place in this particular example with:

```
grid[1,1] = input ("Place a number inside")
```

My question is: How could I set up something that selects a RANDOM row / column for the player to input in instead of me telling it "ok here put it in position [1,1].

Thank you very much and have a lovely day.

Answer (score 1):

Simple case, use `np.random.randint(0, 3, 2)` to make two random numbers between 0 and 3.  Then you can use this to index your array, if you convert it to a `tuple`:

```
rand_point = np.random.randint(0, 3, 2)
grid[tuple(rand_point)] = input("Place a number at %s: " % rand_point)
```

Or you could generate the two numbers separately (this would be important if your array is not square):

```
nrows, ncols = grid.shape   #shape tells us the number of rows, cols, etc
rand_row = np.random.randint(0, nrows)
rand_col = np.random.randint(0, ncols)
grid[rand_row, rand_col] = input("Place a number at [%d, %d]: " % (rand_row, rand_col))
```

If you want to get fancy, you could automatically do this in one line, without having to call `randint` twice, even if `ncols != nrows`:

```
rand_point = tuple(np.random.random(grid.ndim)*grid.shape)
grid[rand_point] = input("Place a number at [%d, %d]: " % rand_point)
```